# Android bindService throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception

I worked through several tutorials to build my first bindService in Android but I keep on getting the same NullPointerException I don't understand. My last example is very simple...

MyActivity.java:

```
package de.123team.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity; import android.content.ComponentName; import android.content.Intent; import android.content.ServiceConnection; import android.os.Bundle; import android.os.IBinder; import android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuItem; import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // Connection
    MySumService mService;
    boolean mBound;

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBound = false;
            //mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mBound = true;
            MySumService.LocalBinder binder = (MySumService.LocalBinder)service;
            mService = binder.getService();
        }

    };


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mBound) {
            mService.unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


        TextView tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        //tvResult.setText("Test123");

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MySumService.class);
        bindService(i, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE); 

        int r = mService.sum(1, 2);
        tvResult.setText(new String().valueOf(r));
    } }
```

MySumService.java:

```
package de.123team.myapplication;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MySumService extends Service {


    private IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return mBinder;
    }


    public int sum(int a, int b) {
        return 666;
    }


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MySumService getService() {
            return MySumService.this;
        }
    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.proteam.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MySumService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>

    </application> </manifest>
```

And the depressing logCat I'm looking at for hours...

```
08-25 10:19:59.809    5107-5107/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.123team.myapplication/de.123team.myapplication.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at de.123team.myapplication.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:86)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: line at MyActivity.java:86 ?

Comment: where is your manifest file?

Comment: you cannot call mService.sum(1, 2); in onCreate,  mService is not yet assigned

Comment: You are right. I moved the lines from onStart to onCreate but the result is the same.

Comment: Please do not use the > sign but just indent with 4 spaces to make the code block appear. Details for formatting can be found in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: this is because bindService is an async operation and still mService is null in onStart,  you can use it only when it it assigned in onServiceConnected method

Comment: @pskink: After reading and trying for hours this is finally the correct answer. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are invoking the method sum immediately after calling **bindservice()** function.

Move below lines of code,

```
int r = mService.sum(1, 2);
tvResult.setText(new String().valueOf(r));
```

to onServiceConnected() function like below,

```
@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mBound = true;
        MySumService.LocalBinder binder = (MySumService.LocalBinder)service;
        mService = binder.getService();

        int r = mService.sum(1, 2);
        tvResult.setText(new String().valueOf(r));
    }
```

It will make sure that your service is bound to your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Please check activity lifecycle. onCreate method is called before onStart method. You are initializing mService object in onStart and using it in onCreate.

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

In onCreate as mService is not initialized and it is null as per default value of object in java, its throwing null pointer exception.

Ideally, you should call sum method from onServiceConnected callback.

Comment: Like a mentioned in my comment above - I fixed that issue but the result is the same.